# how to list file names into a function

Tags: bash

I have a folder with a bunch of files, the files only have a url in it i.e

```
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote/id361285480?mt=8
```

Here is my code. How can I get it to do this for each url in each file?

```
var='{"object":"App","action":"scrape","args":{"itunes_url":"!!!!HERE!!!!"}}'          
string=$(echo "$var" | sed -e 's/"/\\"/g')
string='{"request":"'"$string"'"}'
api="http://api.lewis.com"
output=$(curl -s -d "request=$string" "$api")

code=$(echo "$output" | tr '{', '\n' | sed -n "2p" | sed -e 's/:/ /' | awk '{print $2}')
if [ "${code:0:1}" -ne "2" ]; then
    # :(
    echo "Error: response code $code was returned, "
else
    string=$(echo "$output" | tr '{', '\n' | sed -e '/"signature":\(.*\)/d;/"data":\(.*\)/d;/"signature":\(.*\)/d;/"code":\(.*\)/d' |sed -e 's/\\"//g;s/\\\\\\\//\//g;s/\\//g' | tr '}', '\n' | sed -e 's/"//' | sed '/^$/d')
    echo "$string"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a for loop

```
for filename in folder/*; do 
-- your code where you do something using $filename --
done
```

og if you prefer to give the filenames as arguments to the script then:

```
for filename do
-- your code where you do something using $filename --
done
```

then run your script followed by the files

```
./script.sh folder/*
```

Comment: The problem is I won't know the name of the files I need to use ls or something?

Comment: * means all files in that folder. You could write something like *bla* if you want all files containing 'bla' in their filenames.

Comment: I just wrote folder/* to match all files in a folder called 'folder'.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
for file in *; do
    for line in $(cat $file); do
        # Stuff goes here
    done
done
```

Or even just:

```
for line in $(cat *); do
    # Stuff goes here
done
```

Comment: The problem is I won't know the name of the files I need to use ls or something?

Comment: @lewis: That's what the `*` wildcard is for.  If you want to iterate over all txt files, change the above code to `for file in *.txt; do`.